# Stream desktop to youtube upload

Tags: webcam, screen-capture

I'm trying to record some league matches, but instead of using fraps and uploading them to youtube, I want to select the webcam option so I can just stream them (to save space). How would I do that? I've tried webcammax, video2webcam, and VHScreencapture, but none of them seem to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has a built-in webcam upload feature. You need the free/shareware program (meaning the main part of it is free, but there's paid features too) called manycam. Once you download/install it and set it as default (tutorial [here](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080423215031AAiWNgj)), do the following:

- Go to youtube
- Click upload
- Click "Record from webcam" ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fTyA.png))
- Allow access
- Record your screen!

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer my question.
I want to record/stream my desktop, not from my webcam. Many cam offers features for webcams but I want to turn my screen INTO a webcam.

Comment: Have you tried [camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html)?

Comment: http://i47.tinypic.com/2agra61.png How do I stream this to youtube? Again, trying to turn my screen into a webcam.

Comment: Sorry, try manycam, like I said earlier. Here's an example of how it works: http://i.imgur.com/GsyUK.png

Answer (score -1):

try UScreenCapture from unrealmediaserver
http://www.umediaserver.net/components/index.html